# How i can read my picture on my storage with firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to register my picture on my storage. So basically, my user needs to catch his picture on his phone (with imagepicker) then i want to register this picture on my firestore storage and then register the picture on my User model.

With my function, the picture is registered on y storage , but the path seems wrong

[image]

then when i clicked on the picture she can't being read

[image]

i have also an enabled rejection on my code: Error: [storage/file-not-found] The local file specified does not exist on the device.
NativeFirebaseError: [storage/file-not-found] The local file specified does not exist on the device.

which is weird because the path is registered on my storage.

also my function :

```
 <Icon
          name="camera-retro"
          size={30}
          color="#5DC1D3"
          onPress={async () =>
            launchImageLibrary(
              {
                mediaType: "photo",
                includeBase64: false,
                maxHeight: 200,
                maxWidth: 200,
              },

              async (response) => {
                let image = response.path;
                let reference = storage().ref("PicturesUsers/" + image);
                console.log(reference);

                const pathToFile =
                  `${utils.FilePath.PICTURES_DIRECTORY}/` + response.path;

                await reference.putFile(pathToFile);
                console.log(pathToFile);
              },

              async (response) => {
                firestore()
                  .collection("Users")
                  .doc(await AsyncStorage.getItem("userID"))
                  .update({
                    Picture: response,
                  })
                  .then(async () => {
                    setResponse(response);

                    console.log(pathToFile);

                    firestore()
                      .collection("Users")
                      .doc(await AsyncStorage.getItem("userID"))
                      .get()
                      .then((documentSnapshot) => {
                        console.log("User exists: ", documentSnapshot.exists);

                        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                          console.log(
                            "User data: ",
                            documentSnapshot.data().Picture.uri
                          );
                        }
                      });
                  });
              }
            )
          }
        />
```

Comment: I would guess that there's something wrong with your file - it's saved as jpg, but it's mime-type is binary (application/octet-stream) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#importance_of_setting_the_correct_mime_type .

Comment: Yes but do you think it explained the fact i have  Error: [storage/file-not-found] The local file specified does not exist on the device.  ??

Comment: What is exact translation of the error shown in the image?

Comment: it's ok i fixed it thank you :)